# Vector of Object and pointer in Class Object - Core Dump (segmentation fault)

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, stdvector

I'm trying to create a ROS node in c++11 that would take coordinates stored in a json file to publish them on a particular rostopic (json file is enclosed for you to see the structure).

I decided to create a class object called "DroneTopic" that will read the logs from the json file, create a publisher object and then publish in it.

The main issue I'm facing is the use of a pointer. As the Json type from the library I'm using (jsoncpp) are special type (const signed int for ex) I have to use pointer to take the value and transfer it as an int to the right attribute.

I also use a vector of this class object to handle easier the number of object as I don't know in the beginning how many rostopic I will have to deal with.

The same situation happens inside the class object regarding the number of waypoints. All my drone object won't have the same number of waypoint, that's why I created a vector of a structure (x,y,z) to handle the changing number.

Here is my full code:

```
  class DroneTopic
    {
      protected:
        struct Waypoint{
          int x,y,z;
        };
        std::string topicName;
        ros::Publisher pub;
        std::vector<Waypoint> waypoints;
    
      public:
        DroneTopic(std::string topic,ros::NodeHandle &nh)
        {
          topicName = topic;
          pub = nh.advertise<geometry_msgs::Pose>(topicName,1000);
        }
        //Methodes
        std::vector<Waypoint> read_logs(Json::Value &logs){
          int nb_waypts = logs.size();
          Json::Value *ptr;
          Waypoint tmp {0,0,0};
    
          for(int i=0; i < nb_waypts; i++){
            ptr = &logs[i]["x"];
            tmp.x = ptr->asInt();
            ptr = &logs[i]["y"];
            tmp.y = ptr->asInt();
            ptr = &logs[i]["z"];
            tmp.z = ptr->asInt();
            waypoints.push_back(tmp);
            std::cout << i << std::endl;
          }
          delete ptr;
          ptr=NULL;
        }
    
        void publish_message()
        {
          for(int i = 0; i<waypoints.size();i++){
            geometry_msgs::Pose msg;
            msg.position.x=waypoints[i].x;
            msg.position.y=waypoints[i].y;
            msg.position.z=waypoints[i].z;
            pub.publish(msg);
          }
        }
    
    };
    
    
    std::string filename;
    
    int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {
      //Init ROS Node
      ros::init(argc,argv,"mesa2drone");
      ros::NodeHandle nh;
      ROS_INFO_STREAM("MESA Node Up");
      nh.param<std::string>("Json_File_Name", filename, "output");
      std::string extension = ".json";
      filename+=extension;
    
      Json::Value logs;
      std::ifstream jfile(filename);
    
      jfile >> logs;
    
      // Create vector of DroneTopic
      std::vector<DroneTopic> drone;
    
      drone.push_back(DroneTopic("test",nh));
      int nb_drone = logs.size();
    
      if(nb_drone > 0){
        for(int i=1;i<=nb_drone;i++){
          std::string j = std::to_string(i);
          std::ostringstream flux;
          flux << "intelaero_laserscan_" << j <<"/new_target";
          std::string name =  flux.str();
          std::cout<< "ok_3" <<std::endl;
          drone.push_back(DroneTopic(name,nh));
          std::cout<< "ok_5" <<std::endl;
        }
      }
    
      ros::Rate rate(1);
      while(ros::ok())
      {
        for(int k=1; k<=nb_drone;k++)
        {
          std::cout<<"ok_6"<<std::endl;
          std::string j = std::to_string(k);
          drone[k].read_logs(logs[j]);
          std::cout<<"ok_7"<<std::endl;
          drone[k].publish_message();
          std::cout<<"ok_8"<<std::endl;
        }
    
        //j++;
        rate.sleep();
      }
    
      ros::shutdown();
    
      return 0;
    }
```

I used (but erased for clarity sake) std::cout marker to see where the code is crashing and it seems that it crashes at this line:

```
drone[k].read_logs(logs[j]);
```

It never actually gets out of the function. It executes the full "for-loop" but for some reason I don't get it doesn't get out and gives me this error:

```
Erreur de segmentation (core dumped)
```

From what I saw it has to do with a wrong assignation, but I checked the size of my vector and everything is ok (or so I think).

Any help would be appreciated as I'm struggling with this for a couple days.

Thank you !

FIY: I'm using Linux Ubuntu 16, c++11 (not my choice).

PS: here is the json file I'm using

```
{
 "1": [
  {
   "x": -2,
   "y": 27.5,
   "z": 20.0
  },
  {
   "x": -2,
   "y": 67.5,
   "z": 12.0
  },
  {
   "x": -2,
   "y": 91.5,
   "z": 11.5
  },
  {
   "x": -2,
   "y": 89.5,
   "z": 9.5
  },
  {
   "x": -2,
   "y": 23.0,
   "z": 17.0
  },
  {
   "x": -2,
   "y": 50.5,
   "z": 1.5
  },
  {
   "x": -2,
   "y": 82.5,
   "z": 5.5
  },
  {
   "x": -2,
   "y": 97.5,
   "z": 21.0
  }
 ],
 "2": [
  {
   "x": -2,
   "y": 82.5,
   "z": 20.0
  },
  {
   "x": -2,
   "y": 64.0,
   "z": 0.0
  },
  {
   "x": -2,
   "y": 160.5,
   "z": 11.0
  },
  {
   "x": -2,
   "y": 85.5,
   "z": 14.0
  },
  {
   "x": -2,
   "y": 132.0,
   "z": 19.0
  },
  {
   "x": -2,
   "y": 146.0,
   "z": 1.0
  }
 ],
 "3": [
  {
   "x": -2,
   "y": 137.5,
   "z": 20.0
  },
  {
   "x": -2,
   "y": 156.5,
   "z": 17.5
  },
  {
   "x": -2,
   "y": 28.0,
   "z": 4.0
  },
  {
   "x": -2,
   "y": 67.0,
   "z": 15.0
  },
  {
   "x": -2,
   "y": 40.0,
   "z": 9.5
  },
  {
   "x": -2,
   "y": 81.0,
   "z": 5.0
  },
  {
   "x": -2,
   "y": 77.0,
   "z": 0.0
  }
 ]
}
```

Comment: What did you observe in your debugger when stopping at that line befor the _"crash"_? What's the value of `k` and `j` at that time? I am afraid you're trying to use some already dangling stuff, but that's hard to tell without seeing a [mcve] (emphasis on _minimal_).

Comment: In your `read_logs` function the `delete ptr` feels wrong. Besides you only deleting the *last* assigned value assigned to `ptr`, the pointer is to an object you haven't created with `new` yourself.

Comment: You don't even *need* `ptr`. Why not use e.g. `tmp.x = logs[i]["x"].asInt()`?

Comment: Hi, @Someprogrammerdude I can't use directly what you propose as the Json::Value type isn't just an "int" but a "const signed int" or something like that. 
An error would tell me it can't put a const signed int in an int var.

Comment: `int` is the same as `signed int`. And you can always copy a constant value (to a non-constant variable, and is a reason it makes no sense to return constant values from functions).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The crash happens at the first occurence, k=j=1. The **j** variable is just here because in the json file the keys are string.

Comment: There's also another problem with `delete ptr;`... What happens if `nb_waypts` is zero? You still pass the *uninitialized* variable `ptr` to `delete`.

Comment: Ok I deleted the use of the pointer by  `tmp.x=logs[i]["x"].asInt()` and here is the error I'm getting: 
`free(): invalid pointer
Abandon (core dumped)`

To be noted I deleted all the use of the pointer, I don't create or delete any pointer anymore... I don't get why I have an error about pointer.

Comment: When you run in a debugger, exactly where in your code does this happen?

Comment: I'm using Atom so I don't have the debugger in my IDE. I can just tell that it finishes the loop, it displays the message I put at the end of the function to see if it passes by it and then it crashes.. 
Is it possible that this is the access to `drone[k]=` that causes an issue ?

Comment: Time to go to the command-line and use a command-line debugger. Knowing how to debug ones programs is a *crucial* skill and really mandatory for anyone who wants to program, even for hobby or "just for fun". Nothing beats five minutes in a debugger to figure out things like crashes or other otherwise "unsolvable" problems.

Comment: I can feel the need indeed, do you use gdb or another command_line debugger for C++ ?
Thanks btw for your answers

Comment: For GCC I use GDB yes. There are plenty of tutorials online (and built-in `help` command to show how commands are used), but the three main commands are `run` (to get the program running), `bt` (to display the **b**ack-**t**race, call-stack, when e.g. a crash h appens) and `print` (to print the values of variables).

Comment: Forgot a fourth command that is good to know: `up` to go up the call-stack. For example if the crash happens in a library function you go `up` until you get to your code.

Comment: Ok thank you :) 
My problem here will be that as the script is part of a catkin package I can only compile it with the whole project it's part from. I'm not sure I could compile with g++ directly in command line.

Comment: You don't have to compile from the command line. Build as you usually would (but edit your configuration so it builds with the `-g` flag, to add debug information) and then run `gdb path/to/your/program` (replacing the path to the actual path) from the command line.

Comment: But I'm using `catkin_make` to build my whole project including this .cpp file. So I added in the CMakeList.txt the `-g` flag as you said but I don't get an executable file as I normally call the script using `rosrun` so the format isn't recognized by gdb...

Answer (score 1):

Ok I finally found the main issue.

The `read_logs()` function was set as a `std::vector<Waypoint>` function but I never put the `return` statement as I don't need to get  the vector outside of my object.

That is what was causing the error. I replaced it by `void read_logs()` and it does work now !
What a dummy mistake ^^

Thanks for your help.